# How to add functionality of Enter/Return key in an Edit Control

Tags: c++, winapi, multiline, enter

I know that in Win32 API (no MFC), in an edit control, there's no functionality of enter key. In a standard textbox, when we press the enter key, the cursor jumps to the next line. I want to add that function of the enter key to the edit control.

I tried subclassing and I was able to detect enter key press but how do I jump to the next line?

This is the following subclass :-

```
LRESULT CALLBACK EditProc
(
    HWND hWnd,
    UINT msg,
    WPARAM wp,
    LPARAM lp,
    UINT_PTR uIdSubclass,
    DWORD_PTR dwRefData
)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_CHAR :
        {
            if (wp == VK_RETURN)
            {
               // Add functionality here
            }
            break;
        }
        default :
        {
            return DefSubclassProc (hWnd, msg, wp, lp);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do not need any subclassing. Just set the `ES_MULTILINE` and `ES_WANTRETURN` styles on the EDIT control. You may also want to add the `ES_AUTOHSCROLL` and/or `ES_AUTOVSCROLL` styles, depending on your preferences.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/use-a-multiline-edit-control

Comment: This does not make sense. If you have `ES_WANTRETURN` set, then the focus will *not* be changed when you press the Enter key. [Edit] your question with code that reproduces the problem, please.

Comment: I'm sorry @CodyGray now everything works fine with `ES_WANTRETURN`

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [How to Create a Multiline Edit Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/use-a-multiline-edit-control):

I create a sample with the following code:

```
#define ID_EDITCHILD 100

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd,      
    UINT message,  
    WPARAM wParam,  
    LPARAM lParam)  
{
    static HWND hwndEdit;
    RECT rect;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
        hwndEdit = CreateWindowEx(
            0, L"EDIT",   
            NULL,         
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL |
            ES_LEFT | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL,
            0, 0, 200, 200,   
            hwnd,         
            (HMENU)ID_EDITCHILD,   
            NULL,
            NULL);  

        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

And it works for me:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah finally, I found the answer. I would like to implement what @CodyGray and @ZhuSong-MSFT said and here's the code :-

```
HWND hTb = CreateWindow
(
    L"Edit", L"LOL",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | ES_WANTRETURN,
    0, 0, LOWORD (lp), HIWORD (lp),
    hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL
);
```

This even includes adding a horizontal and a vertical scrollbar.

If anyone wants to dock the textbox in the fill area, I have a solution :-

```
case WM_SIZE :
{
    MoveWindow (hTb, 0, 0, LOWORD (lp), HIWORD (lp), TRUE);
    break;
}
```

Just put the above code in the WndProc function of the main window.